# Inserting output parameters from stored procedure directly

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I have a stored procedure that returns a pair of output parameters - the ID and the computed value. Is it possible to use a trigger with an insert statement, that inserts those two values directly? Something like this

```
CREATE TRIGGER Trig_FirstTable ON SecondTable AFTER UPDATE
AS 
BEGIN
INSERT INTO FirstTable (OtherID, OtherValue)
VALUES (@otherID, @otherValue)
FROM StoredProcedure inserted.ID, inserted.Value, @otherID OUTPUT, @otherValue OUTPUT
END
```

Comment: does the stored procedure update the same data in `SecondTable`?

Comment: To the best of my knowledge, not the way you wrote it. You can execute the stored procedure and use the output variables to do whatever you want in the trigger, but you can't use the stored procedure in a FROM clause.

Comment: you'll have to iterate through records in `inserted`, then call your procedure and then insert into the `FirstTable`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to the [MSDN documentation](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa933206(SQL.80).aspx) you can use INSERT into with EXEC.
They give the following example:

```
--INSERT...EXECUTE procedure example
INSERT author_sales EXECUTE get_author_sales
```

But I think your stored procedure needs a SELECT statement to return the data instead of only filling the output parameters.

Answer (score 0):

You can insert from SP like that:

```
drop procedure uspTest
GO
create procedure uspTest
AS
select 1 as id, 'x' as val
union all 
select 2,'y'
GO

drop table #temp
GO
create table #temp (
    id int, 
    val char(1) 
)
GO

insert into #temp (id,val)
EXECUTE uspTest
GO

select
    *
from #temp
```

But you cannot select a subset of columns, so this method will obviously fail if you add more outputs to your SP in the future:

```
insert into #temp (id)
EXECUTE uspTest
```

Another way is to store SP results in variables, and then use them for insert.